# Using a regex to extract prefixed values from a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string of the form

```
s = "something prefix1 value1 prefix2 value2 prefix1 value3 prefix2 value4"
```

I want to extract the values (value1, value2 etc.) using a regular expression.  There can be any number of value/prefix pairs.  There are only two prefixes.  The values may have spaces.

I've tried things like

```
/((prefix1|prefix2)(.*))+/
```

This doesn't work as the first .* match matches the rest of the string.

I'm working in ruby.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you want to use a split function:

`tokens = s.split(/\s+/)`

This will give you a list of tokens that were separated by white space.

Check out [this](http://zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/Cookbook/Strings/TokenizingStrings.html) section in the ruby cookbook.

**UPDATED:** If you absolutely must match them using a single regex expression, this should work for you:

```
/((\w+)\s+(.*?))+/
```

Comment: I've simplified things a little to create a specific question.  This is part of a set of regexes in a case statement.  There may be a completely different approach to take but for now assume that a regex is required.  Also, the values may contain white space.

Comment: @mattfitzgerald Answer updated with additional regex only solution.

Comment: Apologies if my question was not clear. I specifically want to extract the strings that are preceded by "prefix1" or "prefix2"

Answer (score 0):

Try `/((prefix1|prefix2)(.*?))+/`

The question mark makes it non-greedy.

Answer (score 0):

what's he expected result?
if you simply want to extract values without prefixes try this:

```
str = "something prefix1 value1 prefix2 value2 prefix1 value3 prefix2 value4"

p str.split.reject { |s| s =~ /prefix/ }

#=> ["something", "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"]
```

Comment: I've simplified my requirement in order to post a specific question.   Another way to put it would be;  what sort of regex will match one or more instances of a phrase from which I want to extract a variable?  This sort of thing is usually solved by marking a match group as not greedy.  This works for expressions like `(regex1)(regex2)`.  You just do `(regex1?)(regex2)`.  The issue here is there is only one regex, it's just being used many times. i.e  `(regex)+`

Answer (score 0):

`String#split` can split on a regex:

```
s = "something prefix1 value1 prefix2 value2 prefix1 value3 prefix2 value4"
p s.split(/ prefix1 | prefix2 /) # ["something", "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"]
```